# Unable to Create Logs with NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a .NET application. I'm trying to write some logs using NLog. My app is very basic and successfully runs without throwing an Exception. However, I do not see an actual log file anywhere. How can I get my logs to actually write?

**MyLogger.cs**

```
using NLog;
public class MyLogger
{
  private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  public void Log(string message)
  {
    logger.Info(message);
  }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
static class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var logger = new MyLogger();
    logger.Log("hello");
  }
}
```

I've added the NLog configuration details in the App.config file as shown here:

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>

  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>

  <nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="logFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Logs\MyApp.log" keepFileOpen="true" encoding="Utf8" layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"></target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logFile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="logFile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>  
</configuration>
```

I am not using an NLog.config file. I was under the impression that I could put my entire config settings in the App.config file. What am I missing? How do I write logs to a text file using NLog?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try it to use forward slashes in the path? `fileName="C:/Logs/MyApp.log"`

Comment: I did try using forward slashes in the path. However, that still did not work.

Comment: Is there any relevant information in the Windows Event Log? Also, does 'c:\logs' already exist?

Comment: @NineTails - I do not see any messages in the Windows Event Log. The C:\Logs directory did in fact exist.

Comment: @Tipx helped me solve it. The problem was the encoding. I had to change the encoding to `utf-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the encoding.  it wants "utf-8" NOT "Utf8"

Answer (score 1):

**This will not fix the problem straight, but will help you figure out why it's not working.**

Turn on [Internal Logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) by adding this to your config file:

```
<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">
```

Log that file to the root of a drive to reduce the possibility of it being permission issue. If that still fails, in your debug option make sure you break on everything, and remove *just my code* if it's enabled. Maybe that would help.

Note: Once logging works, don't forget to turn that off as it's a *significant™* hit on performance.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. That helped me fix it. This successfully created the log.txt file. That let me discover that the "encoding" property on the target was incorrect. I changed the encoding to "utf-8" and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that folder "C:/logs" logs is created and application has access to read and write there. You might only have read-only access for `Users` group in the root of C drive. You can test it if you put your log path to `C:/Users/<your_username/test.log`

To create folder automatically, use following config.

```
<target xsi:type="File"
    ...
    createDirs="true" />
```